# django manually set field value

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form with some fields that are not the Model's. i want to fill them out in my **view** before sending it to **render**..

my form:

```
class my_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = my_model
        fields = ['name', 'color']
    non_model_field = forms.CharField(...)
```

my view code:

```
def my_view(request):
    a_model_obj = MyModel.objects.get()
    form = my_form(instance=a_model_obj)
    ## HERE I WANT TO DO SOMETHING LIKE this:
    ## form.non_model_form.set("myValue")
    ...
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set initial values for a ModelForm when instance is also given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254401/how-to-set-initial-values-for-a-modelform-when-instance-is-also-given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this;

```
initial={'non_model_field':'value'}

MyForm(initial={'non_model_field':'value'})
```

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254401/how-to-set-initial-values-for-a-modelform-when-instance-is-also-given